# Select check boxes with "similar" labels

Tags: jquery, dom

the html is dynamic, one example is:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="693b32d9-d776-4df2-bf78-bd3412d9945b" name="permissions">
                 A / B
                 <span class="label label-info invisible">X</span>
             </label>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="b70a2218-6af1-4a5a-a6cf-1454df039d24" name="permissions">
                 A / B / C
                 <span class="label label-info invisible">X</span>
             </label>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" value="db5ffc0f-6733-4d65-a5f0-aafd6411cd8e" name="permissions">
                 A / B / C / D
                 <span class="label label-info">Y</span>
                 <span class="label label-info invisible">X</span>
             </label>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="b08f35be-9e21-4f37-9997-b9dce3b91356" name="permissions">
                  A / B / E
                  <span class="label label-info">Y</span>
                  <span class="label label-info invisible">X</span>
             </label>
         </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

- if one item is checked(for example the third one, with text "A / B / C / D"), then the items with the text "A", "A / B" or "A / B / C", its "X" mark will show automatically;
- if one item is marked with "Y"(for example the fourth one, with text "A / B / E"), then the items with the text "A" or "A / B", its "X" mark will show automatically too;
- All the other "X" mark will hide.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data` attributes.

```
     <div class="checkbox">
         <label data-a data-b>
             <input type="checkbox" value="693b32d9-d776-4df2-bf78-bd3412d9945b" name="permissions" >
             A / B
             <span class="label label-info invisible">X</span>
         </label>
     </div>
```

So when a item with the word "a" changes, all times with the data "a" will change too.

```
$('[data-a] input').on('change', function() {
    $('ul').find('[data-a] span.label').removeClass('invisible');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, custom attributes do help.